# Python : How do you filter out columns from a dataset based on substring match in Column names

Tags: python, pandas

```
df_train = pd.read_csv('../xyz.csv')
headers = df_train.columns
```

I want to filter out those columns in headers which have `_pct` in their substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [df.filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b_pct':[1,2,3],'c_pct':[1,2,3],'d':[1]*3})

print(df.filter(items=[i for i in df.columns if '_pct' not in i]))

## or as jezrael suggested
# print(df[[i for i in df.columns if '_pct' not in i]])
```

Output:

```
   a  d                                                                                                                                                           
0  1  1                                                                                                                                                           
1  2  1                                                                                                                                                           
2  3  1
```

Comment: Filter should be omit - `print(df[[i for i in df.columns if '_pct' not in i]])`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#data from AkshayNevrekar answer
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('_pct')]
print (df)
```

Filter solution is not trivial:

```
df = df.filter(regex=r'^(?!.*_pct).*$')
```

---

```
   a  d
0  1  1
1  2  1
2  3  1
```

---

Thank you, @IanS for another solutions:

```
df[df.columns.difference(df.filter(like='_pct').columns).tolist()]

df.drop(df.filter(like='_pct').columns, axis=1)
```

Comment: The solution with filter is trivial: `df.filter(like='_pct')`

Comment: @IanS - not, because inverted

Comment: what do you mean inverted?

Comment: @IanS - `df.filter(not like='_pct')`

Comment: sorry, got it! so I have another (unserious) solution: `df[df.columns.difference(df.filter(like='_pct').columns).tolist()]` ;)

Comment: or more seriously: `df.drop(df.filter(like='_pct').columns, axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

As `df.columns` returns a list of the column names, you can use list comprehension and build your new list with a simple condition:

```
new_headers = [x for x in headers if '_pct' not in x]
```